# Display all options if user is admin and only one option if not admin in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a stored procedure that returns values from the table. What I want is to return specific values based from options 0, 1, 2 if the user is not admin and then if the user is admin, all options will be displayed and this will happen in one query. Here is the sample code.

```
IF(@isAdmin = 'true')
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 10 *
        FROM [dbo].[inventorydetails]
        WHERE InventoryType = 'active'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 10 *
        FROM [dbo].[inventorydetails]
        WHERE InventoryType = 'active'
        AND OptionType = 0
    END
```

I want to shorten my code into something like this...

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM [dbo].[inventorydetails]
    WHERE InventoryType = 'active'
    AND OptionType = CASE WHEN @isAdmin != 'true' THEN 0 END
```

but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also get the same result without `CASE` with simple condition like following.

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM [dbo].[inventorydetails]
    WHERE InventoryType = 'active' AND( @isAdmin = 'true' OR OptionType = 0 )
```

Comment: You don't need the second check on `@isAdmin`. `@isAdmin = 'true' OR OptionType = 0` has exactly the same truth table as your longer version

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM [dbo].[inventorydetails]
    WHERE InventoryType = 'active'
    AND OptionType = CASE WHEN @isAdmin != 'true' THEN 0 ELSE OptionType END
```